# Why I can't execute scala file?

Tags: scala

I am a newbie to Scala, it's the first time I'm running Scala, when I installed Scala, I created a file named `Hello.scala`, the content is:

```
println("HelloWorld!")
```

when I typed `scala`, there was no problem, the scala REPL was shown, but when I typed `scala Hello.scala`, it prompted:

```
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '.' is found.
```

I dont know what problem is, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 26):

- Adding `-nc` flag saved my day.

  `scala -nc Hello.scala`
- What is `-nc`?

  `-nc          no compilation daemon: do not use the fsc offline compiler`

  Source: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/scala-2.11/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/GenericRunnerCommand.scala.shtml
- What is `fsc offline compiler`?

  `fsc – Fast offline compiler for the Scala 2 language`

  Source: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/tools/fsc.html

Answer (score 16):

To execute external script (load all definitions from it) in REPL use `:load <filepath>` command instead of `scala <filepath>`.

```
» echo 'println("HelloWorld")' > Hello.scala
» scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK Client VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

// is this what you tried to do?
scala> scala Hello.scala
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
   scala Hello.scala

// do this instead
scala> :load Hello.scala
Loading Hello.scala...
HelloWorld

scala>
```

Answer (score 13):

Your file `Hello.scala` is a script.  You should be able to run it from the command prompt with `scala Hello.scala`.

```
$ scala Hello.scala 
HelloWorld!
```

The REPL, on the other hand, is not for running scripts.  It is used for running scala code directly:

```
scala> println("HelloWorld!")
"HelloWorld!"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are executing it in scala REPL .You should be using as below

```
:load [scala file path]
```

output would be as below

> defined "objectname"

Then invoke the main method as the next command

```
objectname.main(Array())
```

Refer the below url for more detailed info

https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2):

Write the `println` statement inside the main function:

```
object HelloWorld {   
 def main(args: Array[String]) {   
   println("Hello World!")   
 }   
}
```

Then execute: `scala -nc HelloWorld.scala`

Answer (score 1):

Just a summary of what I know. I used to be confused by how to run a scala file properly.

In sum, we got 3 ways to achieve this:

1. For script files. For script, it means it's just as the same as you type lines of statements in the REPL, or use `:paste` mode to paste multiple lines. Something like:

   > println("foo")
2. Compile an object containing main method with `scalac`. You can `extends` App trait to easily implement.

   > def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit

You may say "You liar, there are just two ways". But for the second one, I think there's too ways to get it running.

1. `scala -howtorun:object ObjectName -cp "./"`  : The `-cp` is just for insurance.
2. `java -cp "/path/to/your/scala-jars" ObjectName` : So the difference is just the classpath need to be included.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re on some flavor of Unix, you can run a Scala script as a shell script
by prepending a ***pound bang*** directive at the top of the file.

For example, type the following into a file named `helloarg`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
// Say hello to the first argument
println("Hello, "+ args(0) +"!")
```

The initial `#!/bin/sh` must be the very first line in the file.
Once you set its execute permission:

```
$ chmod +x helloarg
```

You can run the Scala script as a shell script by simply saying:

```
$ ./helloarg globe
```

If you’re on Windows, you can achieve the same effect by naming the
file `helloarg.bat` and placing this at the top of your script:

```
::#!
@echo off
call scala % 0 % *
goto :eof
::!#
```

Comment: How can i run scala script from sbt ?

Answer (score 0):

This works in mac for development.

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala -nc
println("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to run scala follow below steps:

1. Dont open scala REPL
2. use `scala <filename.scala><Input if any>` from cmd prompt

below is the example:

`scala  /home/prakash/Desktop/babyname.scala < /home/prakash/Desktop/ND`

**Note:** above command must be typed in unix cmd prompt not in scala repl.