# How to run scala file from command line?

Tags: scala, file, command-line-interface, read-eval-print-loop, scala-repl

Does scala support `scala run xxx.scala`? The go language supports running like

```
go my.go
```

and python supports

```
python my.py
```

but it seems

```
scala xxx.scala
```

is only a syntax check, no output or running behavior is observed. So is there a way to run a scala file directly?

Comment: see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399385/why-i-cant-execute-scala-file

Comment: worth adding some old info is obsolete, like the confusing `-nc` stuff.

Answer (score 3):

`scala` runner's target can be explicitly specified via [`-howtorun`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/06d90464d8d177b927926a2162b342f21239c545/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/GenericRunnerCommand.scala#L102)

```
If the runner does not correctly guess how to run the target:

 -howtorun    what to run <script|object|jar|guess> (default: guess)
```

for example, say we have an fat jar, then we could run it with

```
scala -howtorun:jar myapp.jar
```

By default `scala` runner tries to **guess** and run the named target either as

- a compiled class with a main method
- a jar file with a Main-Class manifest header
- a Scala source file to compile and run

For example, given the following `Hello.scala` source file

```
// source file Hello.scala
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello World!")
  }
}
```

then executing `scala Hello.scala` should output `Hello World!` by the third bullet-point above.

Also consider [Your First Lines of Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/your-first-lines-of-scala.html).

Comment: I had to run `scalac Hello.scala` followed by `scala Hello` to get to output (i.e., compile the source code). How is the source code compiled in your case?

Answer (score 2):

It seems pretty easy. But you have to use println to print something.

```
➜  ~ cat hello.scala
println("hello, world")
➜  ~ scala hello.scala
hello, world
➜  ~ scala -Vprint:parser hello.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // hello.scala
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): scala.Unit = {
      final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>() = {
          super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        println("hello, world")
      };
      new $anon()
    }
  }
}

hello, world
➜  ~
```

or there are a few ways to feed lines to the REPL, which prints results for you.

```
➜  ~ cat calc.scala
2 + 2
➜  ~ scala < calc.scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.3).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> 2 + 2
res0: Int = 4

scala> :quit
➜  ~
```

See also `-i`, `-I`, `-e`, and the `:load` and `:paste` commands.

As shown in the other answer, it will also look for a Java-style main method in an object. That's how you'd normally compile a program entry point.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely recommend `ammoninte` for such cases. It is separated tool but has much more features and works well.

more on http://ammonite.io/

Answer (score 0):

Before running scala source code, you need to compile scala code by using 
`scalac filename.scala` command.
To execute compiled scala file you need to type following command:
`scala filename`

Comment: While this is true, there is a flag to pass everything to the interpreter. You can also write a scala script using the magic `#! /usr/bin/env scala` at the begging of the script.